# Netty large POJO transfer error: TooLongFrameException

Tags: java, nio, netty

I have a netty pipeline such as:

```
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new ObjectEncoder(),
                    new ObjectDecoder(),
                    new MyCustomCommandServerHandler());
```

For both the client and server where:

```
MyCustomCommandServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler
```

The error I'm getting is that the POJO I'm trying to send back from the server to the client is too large and results in the following error:

**org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 1048576: 1816357 - discarded**

How do I adjust the ObjectEncoder/Decoder to take larger sized POJO objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it via the constructor. Just checkout the javadocs.

Comment: Which constructor? I haven't been able to find it in the API's?

Comment: Just found it. But why doesn't it do the same for when you leave it blank since it says it puts an estimated length of 512 and then it should automatically grow?

Comment: Attacker can send a very large object to saturate your heap (= DoS)

Comment: So in the API when it says: "If the length of the serialized form exceeds this value, the internal buffer will be expanded automatically at the cost of memory bandwidth." this is wrong. It doesn't automatically expand, you have to pre-guess the biggest object size...

Comment: And is there a way to automatically increase in cases where I don't know the dataset will be larger than normal?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I might've been confusing ObjectEncoder and ObjectDecoder. You have to set the max for one and the estimate for the other. But what if you don't know the max?

Comment: Then you can specify Integer.MAX_VALUE. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For future readers. This exception is also thrown from `ObjectDecoder` when you send plain HTTP request. If you want to implement regular HTTP server then you should register `HttpServerCodec` instead.

See example [implementation](https://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/netty/how-to-create-an-http-server-with-netty/) and `HttpServerCodec` [docs](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpServerCodec.html).